# Propel Many to many relationship not working

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I am a propel newbie and am running into an issue related to propel many-to-many relationship.
I have two tabels.
Users:

```
  <table name="users" phpName="User">
<!-- column and foreign key definitions go here -->
<column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
<column name="username" type="varchar" size="50" required="true" />
<column name="password" type="varchar" size="256" required="true" />
<unique>
    <unique-column name="username"/>
</unique>
<index>
    <index-column name="username"/>
</index>
<behavior name="timestampable"/></table>
```

Companies:

```
  <table name="companies" phpName="Company">
<!-- column and foreign key definitions go here -->
<column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
<column name="name" type="varchar" size="256" required="true" />
<behavior name="timestampable"/></table>
```

And here is the bridge table

```
  <table name="users_companies" isCrossRef="true">
    <!-- column and foreign key definitions go here -->
    <column name="user_id" type="integer" primaryKey="true" />
    <column name="company_id" type="integer" primaryKey="true" />
    <foreign-key foreignTable = "companies" phpName="Company">
    <reference local="company_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <foreign-key foreignTable = "users" phpName="User">
    <reference local="user_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <behavior name="timestampable"/>
  </table>
```

When I try to get the companies related to users,

```
CompanyQuery::create() ->filterByUser($user)->find();
```

I can successfully get all the users. However, when I try to get all the users related to a company

```
$user = UserQuery::create()->filterByCompany($company)->find();
```

I don't get any users. I also checked the generated sql and it only has one way relationship

```
CREATE TABLE `users_companies`(
`user_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`company_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`created_at` DATETIME,
`updated_at` DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`company_id`),
INDEX `users_companies_FI_1` (`company_id`)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Can anyone please point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe your statement `I also checked the generated sql and it only has one way relationship` is false. It has both relationships; it simply does not have any foreign keys set.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ENGINE=MyISAM which does not support foreign keys. Maybe this has something to do with it.

Make sure your `build.properties` contains the following.

```
; mysql options
propel.mysql.tableType = InnoDB
```

My generated 'bridge' table sql looks as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE `users_companies`
(
    `user_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `company_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME,
    `updated_at` DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`company_id`),
    INDEX `users_companies_FI_1` (`company_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `users_companies_FK_1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`)
        REFERENCES `companies` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `users_companies_FK_2`
        FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
        REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

If all this does not help make sure you are using the latest Propel (1.6.8).

I also have a generated BaseUser::getCompanys() and BaseCompany::getUsers().

Comment: MyISAM does support foreign keys, but it does not support constraints or triggers. I don't think the answer needs a downvote, because siwtching may kick his code into gear, but please update the content to reflect this.

Comment: I believe MyISAM does not support foreign keys as state here (at least for versions <= 5.5): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html. It says "At a later stage, foreign key constraints will be implemented for MyISAM tables as well."

I also believe the solution is to upgrade Propel, I don't think the part of the answer about MyISAM is wrong.

Comment: The answer isn't entirely wrong, it's just the wording. You can add foreign keys in an MyISAM table, just not constraints or triggers. There is a difference.